# Making multiple folders from a list in a text file

Tags: batch-file

Not sure how this could be done or if it is even possible.

But I am trying to figure out how to make a bunch of folders inside of a main folder in my desk top.

Lets say the main folder on the desk top is alphabet and it is going to pull a list of letters a-z from a text file on the desk top.

Then make folders in the main folder for each letter listed.

Is this even possible to pull info from a text file? Would the text file have to be in a specific order on how there separated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test_file.txt :

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Test.bat :

```
@echo off&cls
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type Test_file.txt') do md "%%a"
```

put the two files in the Main folder and run test.bat

Comment: Thank you very much that is what I needed you just saved me so much work!